Error while launching run and debug: Build process failed - wso2 micro integrator with Visual Studio
I have installed WSO2 MI and Visual Studio by follows WSO2 official site
I am trying the simple "Helloworld" service as instructed in WSO2 Quick reference
After designing the project, I am trying "Build and Run" to deploy the created service to the WSO2 MI Server.
However, it always throws an error

Error while launching run and debug: Build process failed
[MI Debug] [ERROR] Error executing BuildTask: Build process failed

I updated Visual Studio by navigating to Help --> check for update and restart also done as per this reported issue in github
However, this issue persists. I am not able to resolve it. Can I get any guidance on how to resolve this?
Environment Details:

OS: Windows 11
WSO2 MI 4.3.0
Visual Studio Code: 1.95.3


The issue seems to be related to Maven not being installed or configured on your system. Please check if Maven is installed.

Hi @Kalindu Gandara,
Thanks for your reply.
Yes it is due to Apache maven not installed to build the project, I have installed Apache maven 3.9.9. now build is successful. after build was successful, a pop up shown like "CApp has encountered deployment issues, please refer to the output for error logs". any suggestion for this issue?
